# R: Efficient way to convert factor into binary matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I'd like to convert a size n `factor` into a n×n binary `matrix` whose (i, j) element is 1 if i-th and j-th element of `factor` are same and 0 otherwise.

The following is a naive way to implement what I want to do but this code is quite slow. Is there any more efficient way to do the same thing?

```
size <- 100
id <- factor(sample(3, size, replace=TRUE))
mat <- matrix(0, nrow=size, ncol=size)

for(i in 1:size){
  for(j in 1:size){
    if(id[i] == id[j]){
      mat[i, j] <- 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I mistook copy-and-paste.

Comment: And instead of `if(...)` just do `mat[i, j] <- (id[i] == id[j]) + 0L`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`outer` can be used for this.

```
mat <- outer(id, id, "==")
```

Since the output is a binary matrix, and O(N^2) objects are kind of large, this is a good use case for sparse matrices:

```
library(Matrix)
mat <- Matrix(nrow=100, ncol=100)
mat[] <- outer(id, id, "==")  # [] means to assign into the existing 'mat' matrix
```

Comment: It's interesting way to use tensordot. Thanks!

Comment: Good answer, but you are not in any way making use of sparse matrices.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative, which should be relatively fast

```
tcrossprod(model.matrix( ~ id + 0))
```

Similarly to Hong Ooi's answer you can use also sparse matrices

```
library(Matrix)
tcrossprod(sparse.model.matrix( ~ id + 0))
```